# Js how to parse content from other side

Tags: javascript, ajax, html-parsing

I need to parse some parts of contents from other sites by enrered url and put it to my page with Javascript.

I need a suggestion how to implement this, what to use. I have tried with AJAX and different Jvascript requests it doesn't work to me. What would be better to use.

Comment: this kind of operation is generally done through server side scripts to avoid Same-Origin policy. JS alone cannot do it unless the source site exposes API or support JSONP.

Comment: It is another question answered, please reopen..